# Ldap autocomplete with Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, autocomplete

Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#responsable").autocomplete('/personquery');
        minLength: "3";


    });
```

And corresponding controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/personquery",method= RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody public void getUids(HttpServletResponse response){

 String personList = null;
 List <Person> ldapUsers = ldap.getUids();
for (int i=0;i<ldapUsers.size();i++) {
    personList+=ldapUsers.get(i).getUid()+"\n";
    System.out.println(ldapUsers.get(i).getUid()+"\n");
}
    }
```

Anyhow, the script doesn't seem to call the controller method. The method can contain some faults too, since I've not been able to test it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using MVC.

We've done something similar in one of our projects. This seems to work:

The script initialises the autocomplete text box. It uses a service call to return a list of user names

```
$("#textBoxId").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("GetADUsers", "ADUser") %>',
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then our action method on the controller looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetADUsers(string term)
{
    List<string> users = SearchForUsers(term); //this is just a method that queries AD
    return new JsonResult() { Data = users.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: Where from is the return type?

Comment: @Mau: Do you mean the return type of the action method? It is a JsonResult. The list of users is parsed into a JSON string array. The jQuery autocomplete then presents the available options from the array to the user.

Comment: Are you using MVC at all? From your question it sounded like you were. MVC's controllers use Action methods (that return ActionResults). JsonResult is just an extension of ActionResult that allows data to be parsed as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). When I initialise the autocomplete in the View, I tell the ajax call to expect a Json data type as the response. If you are not using MVC then my answer most likely won't help you then.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring MVC, but ActionResult/JsonResult in my controller are not recognized. I used your code example, but then again, I'm newbie with all this!

Comment: Ah, my apologies then. I've never worked with Spring MVC. Our project was built using Microsoft's MVC framework. Maybe read up on the Spring MVC framework to see how you can retrieve json results from its action methods.